# Oracle SQL - need dummy date value when there is no data

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select

I query the 'sales' table for 'price', grouping by product name:

```
SELECT product_name, sale_price, sale_date,
SUM(CASE WHEN sales.sale_date = TO_DATE ('14-JUN-14', 'DD-MON-YY') - 1 THEN (sale_price) ELSE 0 END) sale_yday,
SUM(CASE WHEN sales.sale_date = TO_DATE ('14-JUN-14', 'DD-MON-YY') - 7 THEN (sale_price) ELSE 0 END) sale_lweek,

-- below is 10 week slope
-- (N * Sum_XY - Sum_X * Sum_Y)/(N * Sum_X2 - Sum_X * Sum_X)
((COUNT(CASE WHEN sale_date < TO_DATE ('14-JUN-14', 'DD-MON-YY') - 1 THEN (1)
END) * SUM(CASE WHEN sale_date < TO_DATE ('14-JUN-14', 'DD-MON-YY') - 1 THEN (TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sale_date, 'J')) * sale_price) END) - 
SUM(CASE WHEN sale_date < TO_DATE ('14-JUN-14', 'DD-MON-YY') - 1 THEN (TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sale_date, 'J'))) END) * 
SUM(CASE WHEN sale_date < TO_DATE ('14-JUN-14', 'DD-MON-YY') - 1 THEN (sale_price) END))/
(COUNT(CASE WHEN sale_date < TO_DATE ('14-JUN-14', 'DD-MON-YY') - 1 THEN (1)
END) * 
SUM(CASE WHEN sale_date < TO_DATE ('14-JUN-14', 'DD-MON-YY') - 1 THEN (POWER(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sale_date, 'J')),2)) END) - 
POWER(SUM(CASE WHEN sale_date < TO_DATE ('14-JUN-14', 'DD-MON-YY') - 1 THEN (TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sale_date, 'J'))) END),2))
) slope

FROM sales
WHERE sales.sale_date IN
    (TO_DATE ('14-JUN-14', 'DD-MON-YY'),
    TO_DATE ('14-JUN-14', 'DD-MON-YY') - 1,
    TO_DATE ('14-JUN-14', 'DD-MON-YY') - 7,
    TO_DATE ('14-JUN-14', 'DD-MON-YY') - 2 * 7,
    TO_DATE ('14-JUN-14', 'DD-MON-YY') - 3 * 7,
    TO_DATE ('14-JUN-14', 'DD-MON-YY') - 4 * 7,
    TO_DATE ('14-JUN-14', 'DD-MON-YY') - 5 * 7,
    TO_DATE ('14-JUN-14', 'DD-MON-YY') - 6 * 7,
    TO_DATE ('14-JUN-14', 'DD-MON-YY') - 7 * 7,
    TO_DATE ('14-JUN-14', 'DD-MON-YY') - 8 * 7,
    TO_DATE ('14-JUN-14', 'DD-MON-YY') - 9 * 7,
    TO_DATE ('14-JUN-14', 'DD-MON-YY') - 10 * 7)
GROUP BY sales.product_name
```

I have an issue, though, whenever there is no data existing for product_name in prior weeks. The slope equation essentially needs to just treat those missing days as 'zero' values, and plug in the correct julian days accordingly as the 'sale_date'. Is there some way that I could check if past sale_date's exist, and if they don't then create 'dummy' rows for it?

Comment: `to_date()` suggests Oracle, so I removed the MySQL tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is way too complicated, and needlessly.  I see you are computing the slope for a least squares linear regression.  Did you know that Oracle has this same function [`REGR_SLOPE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions151.htm#SQLRF00696)  But to answer your direct question, try removing the `WHERE` clause and doing your sampling with an `OUTER JOIN` instead.

```
...
FROM sales
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
  ( SELECT dt - offset sale_date
      FROM (SELECT DATE '2014-06-14' dt FROM DUAL)
      CROSS JOIN (          SELECT 0 offset FROM DUAL
                  UNION ALL SELECT 1        FROM DUAL
                  UNION ALL SELECT 1*7      FROM DUAL
                  UNION ALL SELECT 2*7      FROM DUAL
                  UNION ALL SELECT 3*7      FROM DUAL
                  UNION ALL SELECT 4*7      FROM DUAL
                  UNION ALL SELECT 5*7      FROM DUAL
                  UNION ALL SELECT 6*7      FROM DUAL
                  UNION ALL SELECT 7*7      FROM DUAL
                  UNION ALL SELECT 8*7      FROM DUAL
                  UNION ALL SELECT 9*7      FROM DUAL
                  UNION ALL SELECT 10*7     FROM DUAL)) sample
ON sales.sale_date = sample.sale_date
GROUP BY sales.product_name;
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about the REGR_SLOPE function. I am having some issues with the my actual query - I am doing something like `SELECT ... FROM sales sa, datatable da WHERE <above code> AND da.product_name = sa.src_productname AND ... GROUP BY sales.product_name;` For some reason it's complaining when I try to replace the first `WHERE` with the `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, any idea why? It's saying something like "sales"."sale_date": invalid identifier.

Comment: Also - I'm not sure if this is doing what I want. The way that I understand the above code is that my sales table is getting filtered to only include today, yesterday and the last ten weeks of the current day. This doesn't give me dummy rows for when rows (say last week and before) are MISSING in sales though, which is what I need.

Comment: Hmm, the `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` is supposed to make sure you get your dummy rows.  How about focusing just on the dummy rows issue and coming back to the regression once we've figured out how to get the dummy rows to generate.  Try with the above code with this: `SELECT sales.product_name, sample.sale_date, COUNT(*) ... ` and change the `GROUP` line to ... `GROUP BY sales.product_name, sample.sale_date;`  If I have the logic correctly, you should see zero counts for product/date combinations when there were no sales.

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing wrong - I did fix my first error, but it's still not yielding dummy rows. If I understand your previous comment, you are trying split up my results into separate days, to check if the dummy days exist? When data exists, the `GROUP BY` works fine. When no data exists I still get no rows. I did get it to work (ish) using this, though: `FROM ( SELECT dt - offset sale_date ... ) sample
LEFT JOIN sales ON (sales.sale_date = sample.sale_date)
LEFT JOIN datatable ON (datatable.product_name = sales.productname)
GROUP BY sales.product_name;`

Comment: Didn't know you had another table in there called `datatable`, so that might have been an issue. Looks like your workaround works.  My suggestion was to do `X RIGHT JOIN Y` to include all rows in `Y` even when unmatched in `X`, therefore producing dummy rows.  Your workaround is `Y LEFT JOIN X LEFT JOIN Z`, which (aside from the additional table) is logically the same, just written as a mirror image.  I think I like yours better anyway, as `LEFT JOINs` tend to be more commonly seen than `RIGHT JOINs`.

Comment: It works, except it won't assign any 'product_name' to the dummy rows - which kind of defeats the purpose, since I am trying to group by product_name. Any ideas for how to get something like: 'for each different product_name, create 12 rows (today, yesterday, last ten weeks.) For each row, look for the product name with that date, and leave blank if none found.' ?

Comment: Makes sense. Then what you need might be a `CROSS JOIN`. Dreadfully also called the Cartesian join, rarely used in OLTP, but you're doing analytics (OLAP), so sometimes a `CROSS JOIN` actually correct. You want ALL your products crossed with ALL your dates, which is exactly what the `CROSS JOIN` does.  Thinking you would want `... FROM sample CROSS JOIN productnames LEFT JOIN sales ON (productnames.productname = sales.product_name) ... `. I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Cross join does indeed accomplish what I want - thanks for your help. I do a `... CROSS JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT product_name as pn FROM sales ) pns LEFT JOIN sales ON pns.pn = sales.product_name AND sales.sale_date = sample.sale_date ...`

Comment: Glad it worked.  You probably noticed in the syntax that the `CROSS JOIN` is interesting in that it doesn't require or even make sense for it to have an `ON` or `USING` clause, unlike any of the other typical joins: `(INNER) JOIN`, `LEFT (OUTER) JOIN`, `RIGHT (OUTER) JOIN`, and `FULL JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

In general when there is no data the value NULL is stored there.
You may be able to use the NVL function to cause your dummy date to be used in the case when the date is NULL.